# Change gridview but not datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataTable`, initalTable, which contains some initial prices. I'm using this DataTable as the `DataSource` for a `GridView`. The user will have the possibility to change some of the values in the `GridView`, but the values from my initialTable are also being modified. How can I bypass this binding? I need to make a cross reference between the values changed by the user in the `GridView` with the ones I stored initially in my `DataTable`.

Comment: Why not take two data tables? Copy one into the other. One for original data and other for modified data. Then put a join and select columns you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk.aspx) method or just plain [clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) the DataTable.

```
private IEnumerable<String> GetChangedWithCrossReference()
{
    return from originalRow in this.storeDataSet.PricesDataTable
               join changedRow in this.storeDataSet.PricesDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Changed)
               on changedRow["Id"] equals originalRow["Id"]
           select String.Format("Was {0}, became {1}",
               originalRow ["Value"], 
               changedRow["Value"]);
}
```

or even better and faster [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private IEnumerable<String> GetChangedWithCrossReference()
{
    return from row in this.storeDataSet.PricesDataTable
           select String.Format("Was {0}, became {1}", 
               row ["Value"],
               row ["Value", DataRowState.Original])
           where row.State == DataRowState.Changed;
}
```